# Cannot access method from another java class

Tags: java, junit

I have this Bank class

```
public class Bank {

    public Map<String, Account> accounts;

    Bank() {
        accounts = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addAccount(String accountType, int accountNumber, double apr) {
        accounts.put(accountType, new Account(accountNumber, apr) {
        });
    }

    public Map<String, Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

and I have another class where I am trying to call the addAccount method from the Bank class

```
public class Processor {
    Bank bank = new Bank();

    public void openCheckingsAccount(String accType, int accNum, double apr) {
        bank.addAccount(accType, accNum, apr);
    }
}
```

I have a JUnit Test class to make sure I can create a new account in the Bank class with the method in my Processor class.

```
public class ProcessorTest {
    Bank bank;
    Processor processor;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        bank = new Bank();
    }

    @Test
    void create_checkings_and_verify_by_id_apr() {
        processor.openCheckingsAccount("checkings", 11111111, 0.6);
        System.out.println(bank.accounts);
        assertEquals(11111111, bank.getAccounts().get("checkings").getAccountNumber());
    }
}
```

But the result of `System.out.println(bank.accounts)` is just {} and I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error when running the JUnit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Processor` class has its own instance of a `Bank`. I guess this is not what you want. That is why when you do `bank.getAccounts().get("checkings").getAccountNumber()` in your unit test you get a `NullPointerException`. You are getting the accounts in the `bank` variable in your test and not the `Bank` object in your `Processor` class.

You will need to change your `Processor` class to receive a `Bank` object in its constructor as follows:

```java
public class Processor {
    private Bank bank;

    public Processor(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    public void openCheckingsAccount(String accType, int accNum, double apr) {
        bank.addAccount(accType, accNum, apr);
    }
}
```

And now also change your test accordingly:

```java
public class ProcessorTest {
    Bank bank;
    Processor processor;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        bank = new Bank();
        processor = new Processor(bank);
    }

    @Test
    void create_checkings_and_verify_by_id_apr() {
        processor.openCheckingsAccount("checkings", 11111111, 0.6);
        System.out.println(bank.getAccounts());
        assertEquals(11111111, bank.getAccounts().get("checkings").getAccountNumber());
    }
}
```

Now there is only only `Bank` instance in your test which is changed by your `Processor` class.

As a side note, please avoid having public properties in your classes (example: `public Map<String, Account> accounts;` in your `Bank` class). They should be private and be accessed via methods in the class. Additionally, keep in mind that when you return the `Map` in `Bank` in your `getAccounts()` method the caller has now a reference to the `Map` and can change it however he may see fit. Having said that, you should consider returning a new `Map` (thanks @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- for the hint on the `Collections. unmodifiableMap`):

```java
public class Bank {

    private Map<String, Account> accounts;

    public Bank() {
        accounts = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addAccount(String accountType, int accountNumber, double apr) {
        accounts.put(accountType, new Account(accountNumber, apr) {});
    }

    public Map<String, Account> getAccounts() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(accounts);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableMap` is usually sufficient for the last case.

Comment: True, thanks @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- for the hint. I will update the code accordingly.